# Codeigniter, how to specify img_url in captcha settings?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone I'm having hard time with Codeigniter captcha library. Browser in my web page do not show any captcha img file, i think it is problem with img_url because img file location is 'http://localhost/blog/captcha/1455115990.3884.jpg' and when i try directly access it throw browser, i just get codeigniter default 404 window, but in my captcha directory in my web project root folder codeigniter successfully creating captcha img files. Any suggestions what i can do differently?

My controller

```
function post($postID){
    $this->load->model('comment');
    $data['comments']=$this->comment->get_comments($postID);
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->load->helper('captcha');

    $vals=array(
        'img_path'=> './captcha/',
        'img_url'=>base_url().'captcha/',
        'img_width'=>150,
        'img_height'=>30
    );
    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', $cap['word']);
    $data['captcha']=$cap['image'];

    $data['post']=$this->Post->get_post($postID);
    $this->load->view('post', $data);
}
```

view

```
 <p>Captcha Code: <?=$captcha ?> <br /><?php
                    $data_form=array(
                        'name'=>'captcha'
                    );
                echo form_input($data_form);
                ?>

            </p>
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my problem was in .htaccess file. I just changed it from

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

And captcha is working!